# My Build Failed Due To /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run ant build-all, but when I do this it says it cannot find 
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist.

I started by executing the build:

cd /home/localhost/trunk

ant build-all

then this was the final result / error:

The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/trunk/kavalok-build/build-all.xml:331: **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist.**

*How do I enable/install java-6-sun-1.6.0.24?*

FULL ERROR:
BUILD FAILED
/var/www/html/trunk/build.xml:82: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/trunk/build-base.xml:81: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/trunk/kavalok-build/build-all.xml:93: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/trunk/kavalok-build/build-all.xml:331: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist.

Comment: "The following error occurred while executing this line:" <= What's the line? Can you edit it in?

Comment: I added in the line, I am missing /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist and I am not sure how to install it in Ubuntu 12.04, please, any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" `sudo find -x / -name javac 2>/dev/null` should tell actual places Java versions are installed to at the host.